# Get the first level of child nodes using QDOMDocument

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm trying to parse an Xml file using QDomDocument.
I've got the root element. Now I need to find and extract specfic nodes
under the root element but only at the first level of hierarchy.

I tried to use:

`QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();`

`QDomNodeList nodeList = root.elementsByTagName("apple");`

But this returns me a nodeList which contains the nodes with tag Name "apple"
in all levels of hierarchy. But I need only a first level search.

Could someone please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no method to do exactly what you want but it's easy to achieve by iterating over the children with something like:

```
QList<QDomElement> elements;
QDomElement child = root.firstChildElement("apple");
while(!child.isNull()) {
  elements.append( child );
  child = child.nextSiblingElement("apple");
}
```